# Why firestore document is not creating nor updating data?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

#### Problem

Firestore document is not creating nor updating data

```
let user = db.collection('users').doc(userId);
let data = {
    timestamp: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        bounties : {
            [impressionId] : {
                timestamp: timestamp,
                amount: amount,
                currency: currency
        }
    }
};

user.set(data, {merge: true});
```

#### Expectation

The below example data should be use to create or update cloud firestore document

```
{
   "example-user-1": {
        "bounties": {
               "example-impression-1": {
                    "timestamp": "12315443",
                    "amount": 0.0,
                    "currency": "null"
               }
         }
   }
}
```

#### Results

The document is not created

```
{"domain":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_eventsCount":1,"members":[]}}
```

Comment: user.set returns a promise that indicates what happened.  Did the promise resolve successfully or not?  If not, what error did it produce?

Comment: You shouldn't have changed an existing question to another question, this is not how SO works. Instead you create a new question every time you have some kind of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

After installing this library and adding this code, it works! but I dont know why.

```
const {Firestore} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
// Create a new client
const firestore = new Firestore();

async function quickstart() {
  // Obtain a document reference.
  const document = firestore.doc('posts/intro-to-firestore');

  // Enter new data into the document.
  await document.set({
    title: 'Welcome to Firestore',
    body: 'Hello World',
  });
  console.log('Entered new data into the document');

  // Update an existing document.
  await document.update({
    body: 'My first Firestore app',
  });
  console.log('Updated an existing document');

  // Read the document.
  let doc = await document.get();
  console.log('Read the document');

  // Delete the document.
  await document.delete();
  console.log('Deleted the document');
}
quickstart();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user.set(data, {merge: true}).then(data=>{console.log(data)});
```